# How should I use my eyes for situational awareness or while defending myself?

Tags: awareness

How do I train myself to be aware of potential threats, or when the threat occurs, to be able to notice when additional threats arise, like the attacker’s gang or his/her friends?

Comment: This is very similar to this question about the "Warrior gaze" https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/10538/5961

Comment: I had seen that question. I was hoping there would be more updated information based on research or used in performance in sports.

Comment: Isn't the answer to this just train? As you get more advanced in your art you would usually advance to multiple attackers, you will gain awareness of distance. And you will learn to tell the difference between a sparring partner who is training and a sparring partner who is fighting.